# Error: Could not find or load main class Mainclass

Tags: java, cloud9-ide

So I followed this site [here](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/java-runner) and I don't think the part where I went wrong was the first part when it was talking about directories and stuff. I'm a real noob. Anyways, when I try to run the java program, it says Error: Could not find or load main class Mainclass. Any idea what's going on? I've tried installing the java jdk but that doesn't make a difference.

Details:

Here's a screenshot of what my page looks like.

[image]

Is there something I should change in my .build file? (I used the same one on the site). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Decide whether to call it `Mainclass` or `MainClass`. Currently you have a file `Mainclass.java` containing `MainClass`.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Note that Java is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a class called Main (or main) with a method like this one:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
     //your main class code here

}
```

**EDIT:**

Try renaming your class to "Main" (no quotes).

**Large Sized EDIT:**

1.You need to make your class `public class MainClass`

2.You MUST have a package declaration!!!

3.You SHOULD probably rename your class to "Main" and your java file to "Main". Other than that, your programming is pretty solid!

Comment: I already have one. Sorry, I don't think my screenshot came through.

Comment: In case that didn't come through either, here's my code.

Comment: class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}

Comment: It's in the screen shot.

Comment: I just tried typing Main but it still doesn't work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: try using eclipse with the same class and see if you get an error

Comment: I have a couple projects that have that same name.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

I cannot see your code but this is a sample code:

```
class greeting {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("hi");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me recently, the Class file saved in your Cloud9 folder has a lower case letter, different from the Class name uppercase

**Filename**:  `Mainclass`
**ClassName**: `MainClass`

[image: Typo in Filename image]

Comment: Are you sure? If it is, please flag the question as a typo.

Comment: @JJJ yes definitely, however, I still don't have flag privilege.